# SVG clipPath to clip the *outer* content out

Tags: svg, clipping, masking

Normally, the `<clipPath>` element hides everything that is outside the clip path. To achieve the opposite effect - that is to "cut out" something from the image - i want to use two paths in the clipPath and the `clip-rule="evenodd"` attribute. Basically, I want to "xor" the clip paths.

But it doesn't work. It shows the region "ORed":

```
<clipPath clip-rule="evenodd" id="imageclippath" clipPathUnits = "objectBoundingBox">
        <rect clip-rule="evenodd" x="0.3" y="0.3" height="0.6" width="6" />
        <rect clip-rule="evenodd" x="0" y="0" height="0.5" width="0.5" />
    </clipPath>     

 <rect clip-path="url(#imageclippath)" x="0" y="0" height="500" width="500" fill="red"/>
```

EDIT:

*My problem is that AFAIK `<mask>` doesn't work in iOS WebKit.*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's much easier to do what you're after with a mask, see [this example](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObject/masking-path-11-b.html). Here's the mask definition:

```
<mask id="maskedtext">
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50" fill="white"/>
  <text x="50%" y="55%" text-anchor="middle" font-size="48">ABC</text>
</mask>
```

Regions that are white inside the mask will be kept, everything else will be clipped away.

Here's [another example](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObject/masking-path-07-b.html) that uses clipPath instead, is a bit trickier since you need to use a path element to get the clip-rule to apply. The clipPath that uses clip-rule there looks like this:

```
<clipPath id="clipPath1">
  <path id="p1" d="M10 10l100 0 0 100 -100 0ZM50 50l40 0 0 40 -40 0Z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
</clipPath>
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add that I can't get `<mask>` working at iOS WebKit. Using `<path>` works, but it is hard to specify an ellipse by points, for example.

Comment: You can specify an ellipse using the arc path command or a couple of curve commands, see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'd seen other examples but your answer is the one which explicitly says, the mask needs `fill="white"`.

Comment: **Using masks hurts performance.** Masks are raster elements (whereas clip paths are vector elements) and many browsers **do not update them every frame**, causing lag if you are to animate them with e.g. `transform` or something similar. Further, they oftentimes don't even work if you animate SVG properties directly!