# invert SVG clip (show only outside path)

Tags: svg

Is it possible to invert the action of a clip with SVG? I'd like to show the path between the two circles rather than inside the circles:

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewbox="0 0 985 740" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
     <clipPath id="re8-clip" clip-rule="nonzero">
        <rect id="sa11" x="763.0" y="176.5" width="70.0" height="25.0" rx="50" ry="50" fill="ForestGreen"/>
        <rect id="sa12" x="516.0" y="127.5" width="70.0" height="25.0" rx="50" ry="50" fill="ForestGreen"/>
     </clipPath>
     <rect id="sa11" x="763.0" y="176.5" width="70.0" height="25.0" rx="50" ry="50" fill="ForestGreen"/>
     <rect id="sa12" x="516.0" y="127.5" width="70.0" height="25.0" rx="50" ry="50" fill="ForestGreen"/>
  </g>
  <path stroke="Black" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" d="M 798.0 189.0 551.0 140.0" clip-path="url(#re8-clip)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817999/svg-clippath-to-clip-the-outer-content-out

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Following the link in Duopixel's comment, the problem can be solved using a `mask`:

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewbox="0 0 985 740" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <rect id="sa11" x="763.0" y="176.5" width="70.0" height="25.0" rx="50" ry="50" />
    <rect id="sa12" x="516.0" y="127.5" width="70.0" height="25.0" rx="50" ry="50" />
  </defs>
  <mask id="re8-clip">
    <rect id="bg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
    <use xlink:href="#sa11" fill="Black" />
    <use xlink:href="#sa12" fill="Black" />
  </mask>
  <use xlink:href="#sa11" fill="ForestGreen" />
  <use xlink:href="#sa12" fill="ForestGreen" />
  <path stroke="Black" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" d="M 798.0 189.0 551.0 140.0" mask="url(#re8-clip)"/>
</svg>
```

As a minor aside, does anybody know if it is possible for a mask to default to white, so the 'bg' rectangle is not necessary?

Comment: about the minor aside, least amount of chars one can get the fill white is with something like: `<rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />` inside the mask.

Comment: You can reuse the tags, replace the two rects in `<mask>` with this: `<use xlink:href="#sa11" fill="#000"/><use xlink:href="#sa12" fill="#000"/>`

Comment: True, but they have to be defined separately since the `use` tag won't override a `fill` attribute. Answer updated, including Ciantic's comment.

Comment: I was using this technique with some objects which are positioned by the user with drag and drop. I found that the objects I was masking were mysteriously disappearing if they moved them too far.

I was able to fix this using the width, height, x, y and maskUnits properties on the <mask> element itself.

Comment: you're a genius RuskiN!

Comment: Can we have a text description of what you're doing here?