# SVG mask doesn't work if a media query is present

Tags: svg, d3.js, mask, clipping

**TL;DR**: I need to mask out a portion of one rectangle in SVG, based on the size and position of another existing rectangle, which will be changing dynamically. A Chrome bug is blocking the `mask` + `use` approach I tried. **How can I do a mask or inverted clip path based on an existing shape?**

**Full Overview:**
I'm using D3.js, and I am using the `brush` control to add a brush to a rectangle in an embedded SVG. By default, this adds some extra elements to the SVG, including a `rect` with class `extent` that shows the size of the brushed area.

Rather than have the brush extent be rendered as a semi-transparent overlay on top of the rectangle, as in most D3 examples, I am trying to "cut out" the extent from a semi-transparent overlay, so that the brush area shows the true color below. Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404391/invert-svg-clip-show-only-outside-path), I am trying to do this with a `mask` element, with a child `use` element referencing the extent. With some D3 magic, I now have a structure like this:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <g class="brush-layer inverted">
    <defs>
      <mask id="mask835">
        <rect fill="#fff" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
        <use fill="#000" xlink:href="#extent848"></use>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <g class="brush" style="pointer-events: none;">
      <rect class="overlay" mask="url(#mask835)" width="100%" height="17"></rect>
      <rect class="extent" x="30" width="52" height="17" id="extent848"></rect>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

This works great... sort of. It turns out that there appears to be a tricky Chrome bug, which [I've filed here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=280927), which prevents the mask from being applied if there's a `@media` query in the CSS. You can see the [working version here](http://codepen.io/nrabinowitz/pen/CBdHb) and the [failing version here](http://codepen.io/nrabinowitz/pen/egrtj) (fails in Chrome, works in FF).

I need this to work in Chrome, and can't drop the `@media` query. I also need to make the `use` element work, because D3 will automatically resize the `extent` rectangle, and that's the shape I need to mask out.

So, **how can I mask out a portion of one `rect`, based on another `rect`, without using the `mask` + `use` strategy above?**

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround might be to use a custom clip-path, but it's probably not going to be as elegant. Some examples of how to do do this with clip-path can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742479/how-to-cut-a-hole-in-an-svg-rectangle).

Comment: The problem here is that, somewhere in the mix, I pretty much have to have a `<use>` element referring to the extent `rect`. The `d3.brush` component dynamically updates the size and shape of that rectangle, and I really don't want to have to track these changes and update a custom `path` element in response. As far as I can tell, there's no way to make this work with `clipPath`.