# d3.js transparent shape tesselations - complex subtractions

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

Expanding on this first example. I am interested to expand the solutions.

1 - make this more responsive - scaling wise
2 - make the subtraction more complex 
3 - ensure the svg fits over the width of the banner.

[d3.js - masking shapes to create transparent sectio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358965/d3-js-masking-shapes-to-create-transparent-sectio)

So here is the goal
[image]

this is the code as it is - I've given it a little clean up.
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1521/

```
function maskMaker(el) {

  var backcolor = $(el).data("color");
  var backopacity = $(el).data("opacity");

  // Set the main elements for the series chart
  var svgroot = d3.select($(el)[0]).append("svg");
  var mask = svgroot
    .append("defs")
    .append("mask")
    .attr("id", "myMask");

  mask.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", "1200px")
    .attr("height", 500)
    .style("fill", "white")
    .style("opacity", backopacity);

  mask.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 550)
    .attr("cy", 250)
    .attr("r", 150);

  var svg = svgroot
    .attr("class", "series")
    .attr("width", "1200px")
    .attr("height", "500px")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")

  var rect = svg
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", "1200px")
    .attr("height", 500)
    .attr("mask", "url(#myMask)")
    .style("fill", backcolor);

}

//var el = $(".mask"); //selector

$('[data-role="mask"]').each(function(index) {
  console.log("test")
  maskMaker(this);
});
```

Comment: well to make it more responsive you can calculate with and height and on window resize redraw/calculate everything

Comment: @RudiUrbanek wouldn't that be a bit slow though -- I do recall there being some scaling features -- its inside a div that will change width naturally - and so maybe even the masking may have to adapt - if scaling isn't enough? -- I'd like to try and get the masking more complex first -- and if anyone knows how to get the color to be more like a photoshop multiply then just an opacity change

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/59bunh8u/43/  -- I've started getting rotated squares going on

Comment: -- this is stating to tessellate - but I think the rotation here makes it much harder to plot - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1522/

Comment: ---I've started to try and get it to loop -- but I am not sure the logic is sound for these tessellations - architect coordinates? http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1523/